# Fastest ALU architecture

Tags: circuit-design, cadence

**I am required to design an ALU which function is to  execute arithmetic and logical operations.The output (arithmetic or logical) is selected by the MSB of the selection line, while the required operation is selected by the other 3 bits.**

[image]

I want to go for the Fastest and most-efficient architectures
either sequentional,static or dynamic what kind of architecture you would advise me to go for to achieve this and why

Comment: You need to do some research, that's the whole point of the task.

Comment: I meant any tutorials or like a fresh head start ? a resource i can read from i did my research but i was out of luck on some issues

Comment: if you are going to post here, then you need to ask a question

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that questions about optimization (i.e., *"What is the best ...?"*) require a definition about what problem dimensions are to be optimized for your application, such as size, speed, energy consumption, user experience, etc. Since these can't be optimized all at once, you need to have a good idea of which ones are most important to you, and be able to articulate that clearly to us.

Comment: Thank you for your reply The most importance for me is the speed and the power consumption @DaveTweed

Comment: @DaveTweed So if i am also required to code the ALU using VHDL and also transistor level block diagram schematics  where should i start  i have searched alot on the internet but came up with no any guides on where to have a head start

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud That's because the design of ALUs has many many constraints, while in fact designing an ALU is a rare task (I think). There won't be many here around who may have ever done such thing. And it can probably not be answered here. You have to break it down into more specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your ALU has 12 bit input, and 8 bit output, so it can easly be implemented as a look up table. 12 bit input means you need EPROM with 12 or more address lines. 4kB EPROM will do job. You can't do it faster and simplier (especialy multiply).

Comment: I agree. See Ben Eater's tutorial on this subject: https://youtu.be/BA12Z7gQ4P0 (OP needs a bit larger address, and ignore 4 bits from the output)

Comment: @Nyos OP need 4Kx8 - on his schematic Arithmetic Unit outputs <7:0> (propably to output MUL a,b result), so OP need not to ignore 4 bits  from output in general, but for most operations you are right.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the multiplication. Yes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but however i beleive i can't use the EEPROM as i am required to make transistor level diagram schematics